# how to dynamically break NHibernation cascade

Tags: nhibernate

The NHibernate cascade setting in the entity mapping is static. Is there anyway to dynamically disable the "cascade" setting in code to avoid expensive cascade operation in NHiberate during a bulky data transaction? We do not want to use stored procedures or native SQL because we need to have the entity changes captured by NHibernate (audit).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable cascading dynamically.

You can use a [StatelessSession](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-statelesssession).

But if you sometimes **don't** need cascading in a particular relationship, just don't set it. Cascade is a nice feature to have, but it's not **required** to make things work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the StatelessSession bypasses the interceptor which will disable the audit function.

Answer (score 0):

you can build up a new sessionfactory using your mappings and interceptor but altering the mapping to disable cascading

```
var config = BuildConfiguration();
var classmapping = config.GetClassMapping("myentity");
classmapping.GetProperty("myprop").Cascade = "none";

var bulkinsertSf = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```